# macos wget exits with error file size limit exceeded

Tags: macos, terminal

My original problem was that on my MacBook `brew upgrade` wasn't working anymore. Then I found out that when I try to wget or curl the sources form the terminal that I get the error "file size limit exceeded".

```
> wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v15.4.0/node-v15.4.0.tar.gz
--2020-12-16 14:26:50--  https://nodejs.org/dist/v15.4.0/node-v15.4.0.tar.gz
Resolving nodejs.org (nodejs.org)... 2606:4700:10::6814:162e, 2606:4700:10::6814:172e, 104.20.23.46, ...
Connecting to nodejs.org (nodejs.org)|2606:4700:10::6814:162e|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 62220902 (59M) [application/gzip]
Saving to: ‘node-v15.4.0.tar.gz’

node-v15.4.0.tar.gz                  50%[===============================>                                 ]  29.77M  12.2MB/s
[1]    7978 file size limit exceeded  wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v15.4.0/node-v15.4.0.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem, with brew, and other programs, unable to make any file larger than 32MB.
There is a built in macOS(unix) support for maximum size limit for files, that can be activated with the `ulimit` command.
To check your file size limit run `ulimit -f`.
If that is the issue you can change it by entering `ulimit -f unlimited`.
If that solves your issue, you should add it as a startup shell command.
For more information on ways to set the limit, I suggest you look at this related Stack Overflow answer https://serverfault.com/a/865809.

Comment: In the end it was not that particular setting you mentioned but something similar.

Comment: Glad you solved it! What was the problem?

Comment: Setting `ulimit -f unlimited` fixed it for me. Among affected were curl, wget, brew, and several package managers. Thank you!